# Displaying text after an onclick event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using click events to log data to the console, but i'd like to display this data in a separate box (which i have created). Does anyone have any advice or suggestions for this? Or is there a decent library that can help me achieve this?

Cheers

```
 var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 7)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d[1]); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d[2]); })
    .on('click', function(d, i) {
        console.log("click", d[0]);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        var result = null;

        if (data.indexOf(d) >= 0) {
            result = colours(d);
        } else {
            result = "white";
        }
        return result;               
    });

var textBox = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 5)
    .attr("y", 385)
    .attr("height", 150)
    .attr("width", 509)
    .style("stroke", bordercolor)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke-width", border);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `"click"` listener just select your `box`, or use the selection you already have:

```
circles.on("click", function(d) {
    selection.append("text")
    //etc...
})
```

Here is a simple demo, click the circle:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .datum({
    name: "foo"
  })
  .attr("cx", 100)
  .attr("cy", 100)
  .attr("r", 60)
  .style("fill", "teal");
var box = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(300,50)");

box.append("rect")
  .attr("height", 50)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke-width", "2px");

circle.on("click", function(d) {
  box.append("text")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .text(d.name)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

Finally, two tips: make your selection a group or any other valid container for the text, **not** a rectangle, because you cannot append a text to a rectangle. Also, be prepared for all kinds of problems trying to fit your texts inside that rectangle: wrapping texts in an SVG is notoriously complicated.

Comment: Man, i was so close... Thanks for your help - One more thing, what is the best practice to reset the text in the box back to empty once another data point has been clicked?

Comment: `box.selectAll("text").remove();`

Comment: @FeelingLikeAJabroni It depends. If you have different texts for different elements, the best idea is setting the selection outside the event handler and, in the handler, setting it to the value you want and then to `""` or `null`, as in `.text(null)` to make them empty. Do not remove and re-append elements in a D3 code, it's not a best practice.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanks for your help with D3, i really appreciate it. I have another D3 question to ask you, where is best to ask it? Here or a new question?

Comment: Always ask questions posting a new question. The comments section is only for clarification regarding the answer. Also, you should not *"ask me"* or ask specifically someone a question: questions are visible for anyone to answer them.